# How do I open up multiple files with find from cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

This is a follow-up to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/how-to-open-multiple-files-from-find-output.

I've already set aliases for both irfanview and NotePad++ (as notepad) but neither of them work.

Here is one of my sample commands:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec notepad {} +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a for loop

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt" -print)
do
   notepad $file &
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is using -print important here?

Comment: It should not be required.. Better to put it when you post on forums as you never know if the person you are helping may be using a version of the tool that is more strict :). Also note the & on the command line.. that tells it to start the process in the background, which is key or it would pause on each notepad call.